# Do I need all these HTML5 tags for my site’s master header?

Tags: html, semantics

I began learning html/css and throughout my learning I have seen the idea of semantics stressed heavily. Most of the time I understand what I should be using and everything works out fine. But there are many times when it feels like there are far too many tags for something simple, for instance:

suppose I have a master header on my site with some links for navigation, semantically I get this:

```
<section id="masterHeader">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> link </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
     </header>
</section>
```

Is this too much, or should I be doing this as it does make complete sense? It just seems like a lot of unneeded tags.

Comment: Why do you wrap the header into a section? I think a header is just a specialized section and should used this way. Except this your markup looks fine to me.

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-header-element makes it sound like it should be in a section, or perhaps I should be using a section as a container, and then using the header within the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems quite unnecessary to have your header tag within the section tags. instead, it should look something like this:

```
<header id="masterHeader">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    <nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Off-topic sort of question: what should I use if I wish to have a container (wrapper) around all of the content within the body, should I use section or div?

Comment: w3c has defined it with the following: "The <section> tag defines sections in a document, such as chapters, headers, footers, or any other sections of the document."

the thing is, if we already have the header and footer tags in this case, then if would be very unlikely that the section tag is for the purpose of holding them. 

you can refer to this article - http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/ - for some idea of how you should be using the section tag instead.

having said that, i would recommend using a div wrapper instead.

hope that helps =)

Comment: Edit: read your edit, thank you very much, it now makes more sense!

Comment: no problem. here's another good article touching on the usage of the section tag. http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of semantically designing a page is not because it is easier for you as a designer to read (though thats a good benefit) or because it is more lightweight (it often isnt). Rather, the purpose of semantic design is to add meaning to your code that simply making divs with IDs and classes cannot accomplish. A search engine crawling your site can, ostensibly understand your code far better when it is semantically marked up.

The problem is, IE8 and lower do not natively support these semantic elements and thus require a js shiv. But then your layout breaks in IE8 and lower if they have JS disabled. This is a tradeoff you will have to seriously weigh before you consider using HTML5 elements as your layout WILL break in IE8-6 with no-js.

Also, I would argue that the section element is not semantically correct in your usage here (but I may be wrong, I'd have to check the w3c spec). But that is neither here nor there, and mostly just nit-picking.

Comment: Wouldn't the header be a section of the page? That is why I have section there.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section : "The section element is not a generic container element. The section element is appropriate only if the contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline."  In your case, you are using the section element only as a container to the header section of a page. But if you dissect your page like that, that means that the footer and container are sections, and then the subsections within the container are sections too. Instead, section should only be used to group thematic content like a chapter of a book, or an intro, outro, and body text

Comment: @Moses -- usually, it's spelled "shim" but we often *want* to use a shiv on IE :-)

Comment: @Pete http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/ was the first time I heard about the HTML5 fix, so since then I've always called it shiv. Either way, I know I've wanted to shiv IE on more than one occasion, so I think I'll continue to use that terminology.